# Iterate over enum, assign enum element as parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I want to iterate over an enum. When I iterate over this enum i get the key and the value, but I want only to add Intances of Skill to the skills array with the keys.

```js
enum eSkills {
    ACROBATICS = <any>"Acrobatics",
    APPRAISE = <any>"Appraise",
    BLUFF = <any>"Bluff",
    CLIMB = <any>"Climb",
    CRAFT = <any>"Craft"
}

class Skill {
    constructor(name: eSkills) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    name: eSkills;
}

let skills: Skill[] = [];

for (let skill in eSkills) {
    //TODO create new instance of Skill and push to skills array
}
```

I need the reverse mapping of the enum.

Comment: you want to iterate over the `eSkills` enum and push only the keys?

Comment: so, `skills.push(new Skill(skill))`?

Comment: there is an error for  `new Skill(skill)` --> _Argument of type "string" is not assignable to parameter of type "eSkills"._.

And in `skills` are alsoelements with name equal the values of the enum.

@Sagivb.g yes.

Comment: If you need just the keys then shoudn't `name` be typed as `string` instead of `eSkills`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you already tried this to no avail:

```
skills.push(new Skill(skill)); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'eSkills'.
```

You can fix that by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (`as eSkills`):

```
skills.push(new Skill(skill as eSkills));
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterating-enum-keys-in-typescript)

Comment: when I add the any assertion to the enum values. There is another error and also Skills with the enum values as name will be pushed to the array.

I need the anny assertion for the reverse mapping of the enum.

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterating-enum-keys-in-typescript-bjq4fe) as example. The error is _Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'eSkills'_